# How to flip three images infinitely?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
setInterval(() => {
// Loop every 12s

    setTimeout(() => {
        // Flip Images from bg3 & bg4 to bg1 & bg2 => from Plane to Dog
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.transform = "rotateX(0deg)";
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Change bg3 & bg4 background-image => from Plane to Night View
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/kS4XvCS/night.png')";
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/kS4XvCS/night.png')";
    }, 4000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Edit CSS properties bg1 & bg2 => Dog
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transformOrigin');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transition');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transformStyle');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('backfaceVisibility');

        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transformOrigin = "top";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transition = "1s";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.backfaceVisibility = "hidden";
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(() => {
    // flip bg1 & bg2 to bg3 & bg4 => from Dog to Night View
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.transform = "rotateX(0deg)";
    }, 6000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Change bg1 & bg2 background-image => from Dog to Plane
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/fHtHx3Q/plane.jpg')";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/fHtHx3Q/plane.jpg')";
    }, 7000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Edit CSS properties bg3 & bg4 => Dog
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.removeProperty('transformOrigin');
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.removeProperty('transition');
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.removeProperty('transformStyle');
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.removeProperty('backfaceVisibility');

        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.transformOrigin = "top";
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.transition = "1s";
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.backfaceVisibility = "hidden";
    }, 8000);

    setTimeout(() => {
    // flip bg3 & bg4 to bg1 & bg2=> from Night View to Plane
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.transform = "rotateX(180deg)";
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.transform = "rotateX(0deg)";
    }, 9000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Change bg3 & bg4 background-image => Night View to Dog
        document.querySelector(".bg3").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/KVdwQ4d/dog.png')";
        document.querySelector(".bg4").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.ibb.co/KVdwQ4d/dog.png')";
    }, 10000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      // Edit CSS properties bg1 & bg2 => Plane
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transformOrigin');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transition');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('transformStyle');
        document.querySelector(".bg1").style.removeProperty('backfaceVisibility');

        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transformOrigin = "top";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transition = "1s";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.transformStyle = "preserve-3d";
        document.querySelector(".bg2").style.backfaceVisibility = "hidden";
    }, 11000);
  
}, 12000);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #eee;
    perspective: 9999999999px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

.bg1 {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/KVdwQ4d/dog.png");
    background-position: top;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.bg2 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/KVdwQ4d/dog.png");
    background-position: bottom;
}

.bg3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fHtHx3Q/plane.jpg");
    background-position: top;
  
}

.bg4 {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fHtHx3Q/plane.jpg");
    background-position: bottom;
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="bg2"></div>
    <div class="bg3"></div>
    <div class="bg1"></div>
    <div class="bg4"></div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to make a **carousel** changes the image every 12 seconds and repeats the process infinitely, But I couldn't do that even though I understood the main idea (**Replace Class**).

It's easy to do this with two images but when it comes to three images everything changes.

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/Muh-Ail/pen/RwjEPLm

Comment: Why not use some already implemented library?

Comment: And your one `setTimeout` should call another `setTimeout`

Comment: There's a fundamental programming issue here. Basically you're hardcoding everything. Your image urls should exist in an array (or as data properties of the divs? or in regular img tags - you can still object-fit an img tag). Then, instead of hard-coding the classes in JS, do a querySelector**All** to get a NodeList of the items, *or* find the parent by an ID and then create the child objects based on an array, or find the child img tags, or whatever. Then use LOOPS to do the job. That way you can get it working no matter how many images you want to loop through.